# Reading Triangle Data Mesh With Object Files

Tags: c++, object, mesh

I need to load in the vertices of a .obj file in c++. I just copied over the verts from the object I downloaded so I didn't have to worry about texture mapping or anything. I was able to separate it into a single line and get rid of the v but am not able to isolate the x,y,z coordinates so I can assign it to three separate variables.

main.cpp

```cpp
// ConsoleApplication3.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. Program execution begins and ends there.
//

#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string pos1, pos2, pos3;

int main()
{
    string line;
    ifstream myfile("fox.txt");
    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        while (getline(myfile, line))
        {
  
            line.erase(std::remove(line.begin(), line.end(), 'v'), line.end());
            cout << line << endl;
        }
        myfile.close();
    }

    else cout << "Unable to open file";

    return 0;


}
```

fox.txt

```
v 10.693913 60.403057 33.765018
v -7.016389 46.160694 36.028797
v 9.998714 51.307644 35.496368
v -8.642366 49.095310 35.725204
```

Comment: For every line, can't you first read in a char (to get rid of the 'v'), then read in three doubles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to read in the line

`v 10.693913 60.403057 33.765018`

and separate it into 3 different variables is to first read in a `char`, then read in three `doubles`:

```
ifstream fin("fox.txt");

vector <vector<double>> data; // holds sets of coordinates
double a, b, c;
char v;

while(fin >> v >> a >> b >> c){
    data.push_back({a, b, c});
}
```

If you wanted, you could also use `std::stringstream` to parse the input into `doubles`.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way is to simply use **std::stringstream** and treat it like you would any other stream.

```
#include <sstream>
...
std::string pos1, pos2, pos3;
std::stringstream lineStream;
...
while (getline(myfile, line))
{
    /* Make a string stream out of the line we read */
    lineStream.str(line);
    
    char skip; // Temp var to skip the first 'v'
    lineStream >> skip >> pos1 >> pos2 >> pos3;

    /* Reset error state flags for next iteration */
    lineStream.clear();
}
```

Or you could avoid all that by using the `>>` operator on `myfile` directly.

```
std::string temp, pos1, pos2, pos3;

while (myfile >> temp >> pos1 >> pos2 >> pos3)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to figure you want to store this data in the likes of a `std::vector`. This is one way of doing it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

const char* test_str = R"(
v 10.693913 60.403057 33.765018
v -7.016389 46.160694 36.028797
v 9.998714 51.307644 35.496368
v -8.642366 49.095310 35.725204
)";

struct data_item {
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
};
using data_set = std::vector<data_item>;

int main()
{
    //std::ifstream myfile("fox.txt");
    //if (!myfile.is_open()) {
    //    std::cout << "Unable to open file\n";
    //    return -1;
    //}
    std::stringstream as_file;
    as_file << test_str;
    data_set set;
    for (; ;) {
        std::string dummy;
        data_item item;
        as_file >> dummy >> item.x >> item.y >> item.z;
        if (!dummy.size())
            break;
        set.push_back(item);
    }
    for (auto& item : set)
        std::cout << item.x << " " << item.y << " " << item.z << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Don't do: `using namespace std;` It will save you a lot of headaches down the road. It also makes your code more readable to know stuff is out of the standard library.

When testing, it is sometimes more simple to use local data as I have with `test_str`. As pointed out in the comments, you could just let the stream do the conversion from text to doubles.

Note I've taken care of a failed file error in one place, the commented file stuff. Putting an else way down from the failure is not so clear and creates a large unneeded scope.